# Next Js Api routes response helpers (redirect)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sanity

I'M trying to create a login functionality in Next js.
Everything is pretty much done but I'm unable to redirect to homepage after login.
I'm using Next js with sanity as headless CMS
This is my login api

```
export default async function CreateComment(req, res) {
    const { email, password , user } = JSON.parse(req.body)
    console.log(password , "123")
    const Alluser = user.map((item)=>{
        return item.email
    })
    const UserPassword = user.map((item)=>{
        return item.password
    })
    if (Alluser.includes(email) && UserPassword == password){
        console.log(email)
    }
    res.redirect(307, '/').status(200).send('Success')
}
```

After Login Error in terminal

[image: error in terminal]

Response in network #1

[image: Reponse #1]

Response in network #2

[image: Response #2]

Answer (score 1):

Use the redirect as follows

```
res.redirect(307, '/');
```

[Redirects to a specified path or URL](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/response-helpers#redirects-to-a-specified-path-or-url)